# select distinct rows order by Id Asc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to select rows that have a distinct Title Column.

```
Id  Title     Type
1   Bronze    Group
2   Bronze    Group
3   Bronze    Group
4   Silver    Group
5   Silver    Group
6   Silver    Group
7   Gold      Group
8   Gold      Group
9   Gold      Group
10  Platinum  Group 
11  Platinum  Group
12  Platinum  Group
```

I thought this would be a simple query but i'm struggling! If anyone can help that would be great

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Title), Id
FROM Package 
WHERE Type='Group'
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

Comment: What what should be the output for `id`?

Comment: @juergend Id is my Primary key column

Comment: Yes, but there are *multiple* rows with the same `Title` and *different* `Id` values - which *rows* `Id` value should be used for any particular `Title`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by the `title`. And you have to tell the DB which rule to apply when selecting the `id` for duplicate entries. For instance the smallest `id` for every unique `title`:

```
SELECT Title, min(Id) as minid
FROM Package 
WHERE Type='Group'
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY min(Id) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to drop the ID off as it is unique and makes it DISTINCT. Something like this.

SELECT DISTINCT Title
FROM Package 
WHERE Type='Group'